# Вычислить количество коммитов в Git репозитории с определенным словом в комментарии

Tags: git

Как в гите можно узнать количество коммитов с определенным словом в комментарии коммита. Хочу узнать сколько коммитво было сделано со словом к примеру "STACK" в комментарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$ git log --grep='STACK' --oneline | wc -l
```

Возможно, у `git-log` есть флаг для подсчёта
коммитов без перенаправления в `wc`, но я его пока
не нашёл.

Даты:

```
$ git log --after='2020-01-01T00:00:00Z' --before='2021-01-01T00:00:00Z' --oneline | wc -l
```

Comment: Да, работает, как можно узнать сколько коммитов было сделано за последний год?

Comment: @JMas  Это лучше было отдельным вопросом, но добавил.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: Как вариант `git log --grep='STACK' --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=short | grep 2020 | wc -l`

Comment: Спасибо, да понимаю, но может быть для вас это было бы как дважды два, к тому же я уже отметил ваш вопрос принятым